# How can I register a custom HttpMessageConverter to deal with an invalid Content-Type in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing code to `POST` data to a third party API using a `RestTemplate`. That API responds with the content-type `text;charset=UTF-8`, and Spring throws an `InvalidMediaTypeException` because that content type does not contain a `/`. Is it possible to indicate to Spring that a content-type of `text` should be treated the same as a content type of `text/plain`? If so, how do I accomplish this?

This is the code that's causing the problem. I can't show the `URL`, but I assume that doesn't really matter.

```
// Make the body of the request.
MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
body.add("Customer Street", "a test street!");

// Make the headers of the request.
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

// Create an HTTP entity.
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(body, headers);

// Get a rest template
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

// Post the data.
String resp = null;
try {
    resp = rest.postForObject(URL, entity, String.class);
} catch (InvalidMediaTypeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

## Related SO Questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657806/spring-resttemplate-throws-invalidmediatypeexception) question describes almost exactly the problem I'm having. The accepted answer to that question is, essentially, "See this other question," which I did; it's described below.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185375/how-to-configure-custom-mediatype-in-spring-mvc) question (linked in the answer to the above), [istibekesi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3612124/istibekesi) asks about using a custom content-type of `myXml`, and provides an example configuration that did not work. [Brian Clozel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22982/brian-clozel) answer helped me understand some things about content-types that I didn't understand before, but I'm still confused on these points:

1. Brian says that the given configuration should register `myXml` as a path extension / parameter for negotiating to `application/xml`. My initial understanding was that Brian meant, "Requests with the accept header set to `myXml` should be treated the same as requests with the accept header set to `application/xml`." However, now I'm pretty sure Brian meant, "Requests ending in `.myXml` or with the query parameter `format=myXml` should be treated as `application/xml`." Is my second interpretation correct? If so, why *doesn't* the given configuration force Spring to treat requests with the accept header set to `myXml` as `application/xml`?
2. Brian states that what istibekesi should probably do is register an `HttpMessageConverter` and then register it with `application/xml` and `myXml`. I think I understand what Brian means by saying, "register an `HttpMessageConverter`," however I can't figure out how to register a custom media type (such as `myXml`) to use that `HttpMessageConverter`.
3. Unfortunately, Brian's advice of "use a media type like `application/vnd.foobar.v.1.0+xml`" isn't helpful to me, because I have no control over the content-type of the response that I'm sent. I have tried setting the accept headers of my request to `text/plain`, but it didn't change the response.

## Other Research

The stack trace of the exception that Spring is throwing is

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "text;charset=UTF-8": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:452)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
    at com.agileBTS.hellosignTest.App.main(App.java:47)
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "text;charset=UTF-8": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:256)
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:449)
```

I went through the source code of every function on the stack trace to see if I could figure out what was going on, and I can see clearly that the `parseMimeType` method (the first method to throw an exception) is pretty straightforward: if the mime-type does not contain a `/`, it throws an exception. I don't understand how any code is going to get around this, unless I subclass `MimeTypeUtils` and force Spring to use my subclass. Is that what's required? That seems very difficult.

## Updates

### 1

In their answer, [Sean Carroll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252243/sean-carroll) suggested that I register the `"text"` mime type using the line

```
c.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.parseMediaType("text")));
```

However, if you check out the source code for the `#parseMediaType` method [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java) at line 487, you'll see that `#parseMediaType` hands off most of the work to the `MimeTypeUtils#parseMimeType` method. Looking at *that* source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/MimeTypeUtils.java) starting at line 176, it's clear the `#parseMimeType` will throw an `IllegalMimeTypeException` at line 193, because `"text"` does not contain a `/` (in fact, this is the exact line of code that throws the `IllegalMimeTypeException` in my application). What I need is a way around this.

### 2

After testing, I've determined that configuring a Content Negotiation Manager also does not work in my case. Based on [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) tutorial, I think it's clear that the XML configuration:

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
       </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

is equivalent to this Java configuration:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
configurer.mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

Taking a look at the `ContentNegotiationConfigurer#mediaType` method documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html#mediaType-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.MediaType-), I saw the line, "Add a mapping from a key, **extracted from a path extension or a query parameter**..." (emphasis mine); I guess excluding "accept headers" from that quote was intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to register a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` with a `RestTemplate` which allows for editing of client responses before Spring does anything to them. To solve my problem, I created a class that implements `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and overrode the `intercept` method to replace all instances of `text;` with `application/json;` in the `Content-Type` header. I then registered my `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` with my `RestTemplate` bean definition, so that any time I autowire a `RestTemplate`, it has this interceptor on it.

Code for my `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`:

```
public class ContentTypeTextToTextJson implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentTypeTextToTextJson.class);

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {
        LOG.debug("intercepting execution");

        // Get the response as normal.
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        LOG.debug("intercepted response: " + response);

        // Get the headers.
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        LOG.debug("response had headers: " + headers);

        // Grab all the content types.
        List<String> contentTypes = headers.get("Content-Type");
        LOG.debug("response had content-types: " + contentTypes);

        // Loop over the content-types.
        for(int i = 0; i < contentTypes.size(); i++) {
            String contentType = contentTypes.get(i);
            LOG.debug("processing content type: " + contentType);
            // I'm not sure if it's possible for a content-type to be null, but I guess it's
            // better safe then sorry?
            if(null == contentType) {
                continue;
            }
            // If it starts with "text;", replace "text" with "text/json" and replace the old content type.
            if(contentType.startsWith("text;")) {
                contentType = contentType.replaceFirst("text", "application/json");
                LOG.debug("replacing content type " + contentTypes.get(i) + " with content type " + contentType);
                contentTypes.set(i, contentType);
            }
        }

        // Return the response.
        return response;
    }

}
```

RestTemplate bean definition:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="restinterceptors.ContentTypeTextToTextJson" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This is how I interprets Brian's answer. I'm assuming you are using java configuration. To register an HttpMessageConverter you would do something like the following</strike>

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();

        // add support for "text" media type. This may require Charset of UTF-8
        c.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.parseMediaType("text")));
        converters.add(stringMessageConverter);
    }

}
```

Edit: How about using content negotiation manager to map text to text/plain? From javadocs

> For the path extension and parameter strategies you may explicitly add MediaType mappings. This will be used to resolve path extensions or a parameter value such as "json" to a media type such as "application/json".

The docs explicitly mention extensions and parameters and I'm not completely sure but it may also work on accept headers (I would need to dig into the code more). If it doesn't you may need to look at a custom ContentNegotiationStrategy

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="mediaTypes" >
        <value>
            text=plain/text
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the response. Unfortunately I'm using XML configuration, but I'll look into converting your suggestion to an XML equivalent and get back to you about how it goes.

Comment: Hi again Sean. I've added an **update** to my question describing why I believe your answer won't work. If you have any other ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: Edited my answer. Have you looked at contentNegotiationManager and/or custom ContentNegotiationStrategy?

Comment: Another alternative I'm looking at is to customize RestTemplate. It has a couple of hooks that might be helpful such as acceptHeaderRequestCallback and ResponseExtractor

Comment: This all looks really useful, I'll look into it and get back to you. Thanks so much for your help thus far!

Comment: Unfortunatley, using a ContentNegotiationManager didn't work - I guess not mentioning accept headers in the docs was intentional. I'll look into a custom ContentNegotiationStrategy next.

Comment: @RobsterLobster is the third party API you're using public?

Comment: No, but you can create a free account if you really, really want to. The service is Zoho Creator, and the endpoint is https://creator.zoho.com/api/{username}/json/{application-name}/form/{form-name}/record/add/