# How to set priority to Spring-Boot request mapping methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping, content-negotiation

I have a Spring-Boot (v2.0.2) application with a RestController with 2 methods which only differ by the Accept header. A simplified version of the code is this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myapp")
public class FooController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/foo/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<String> fooJson(@PathVariable id) {
        return foo(pageId, true);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/foo/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/ld+json", produces = "application/ld+json;charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<String> fooJsonLd(@PathVariable id) {
        return foo(pageId, false);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<String> foo(String id, boolean isJson) {
        String result = generateBasicResponse(id);
        if (isJson) {
            return result
        }
        return addJsonLdContext(result);
    }
```

This works fine. If we sent a request with accept header such as `application/json;q=0.5,application/ld+json;q=0.6` for example it will return a json-ld response as it should.

My problem is that if we sent a request with no accept header, an empty accept header or a wildcard `*/*` then it will by default always return a json response whereas I want the default response to be json-ld.

I've tried various things to make the json-ld request mapping take priority over the json one:

- Reversing the order in which the mappings are declared.
- Adding an @Order annotation to both methods (with value 1 for json-ld and value 2 for the json method)
- Creating different classes and putting the @Order annotation at class-level
- Adding `Accept=*/*` as a second accept header to the json-ld mapping does work in giving it preference but has the unwanted side-affect that all accept headers are accepted, even unsupported types as `application/xml` for example.

The only solution I can think of is creating one request-mapping method that accepts both headers and then processing the accept header ourselves, but I don't really like that solution. Is there a better, easier way to give preference to json-ld?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching [this question on configuring custom MediaTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27185375/741249) pointed me in the right direction.
The WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (Spring 3 or 4) or WebMvcConfigurer (Spring 5) allows you to set a default mediatype like this:

```
public static final String MEDIA_TYPE_JSONLD  = "application/ld+json";

@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.valueOf(MEDIA_TYPE_JSONLD));
    }
}
```

This works great for requests with no or an empty accept header, as well as `accept: */*`. However when you combine an unsupported type with the wildcard, for example `accept: */*,text/plain` it will return json instead of json-ld!? I suspect this is a bug in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue using the `consumes` in the `@GetMapping` annotation. [According to the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--):

> The format is a single media type or a sequence of media types, with a request only mapped if the Content-Type matches one of these media types. Expressions can be negated by using the "!" operator, as in "!text/plain", which matches all requests with a Content-Type other than "text/plain".

In the solution bellow, note that I've added the consumes array to the normal json request mapping, making the client only be able to use the json endpoint if it have the correct `Content-Type`. Other requests go to the `ld+json` endpoint.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/json", headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public String testJson() {
    return "{\"type\":\"json\"}";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/json", headers = "Accept=application/ld+json")
@ResponseBody
public String textLDJson() {
    return "{\"type\":\"ld\"}";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work for me. Requests that come in do not have a Content-type header so when I add consumes to the json method then any request with `Accept : application/json` header will return a 406.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't noticed that post-man added the Content-Type header to the request, faking my results. I dived deep into the problem and there is only one way to solve it. Creating a Filter, which adds a "Content-Type" header based on the "Accept" header sent by the client. In my opinion, this solution is super ugly but works for all requests in the application.

If you think that adding another method to the controller is worse than this solution, I can share more details.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I actually found a better solution and posted it as an answer.